# How to set height and width of JavaFX TextArea?

Tags: java, javafx-8

```
TextArea txt = new TextArea();
```

What method do I call to set the height and width of this `TextArea`?

Comment: `setPrefColumnCount()` and `setPrefRowCount()` should do it for you. [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html#getPrefColumnCount--)

Comment: Thanks that worked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea(); //making a TexrArea object
double height = 400; //making a variable called height with a value 400
double width = 300;  //making a variable called height with a value 300

//You can use these methods
textArea.setPrefHeight(height);  //sets height of the TextArea to 400 pixels 
textArea.setPrefWidth(width);    //sets width of the TextArea to 300 pixels
```

Comment: Please consider adding some details and explanation to support your answer in order to help others

Answer (score 5):

setPrefColumnCount() and setPrefRowCount() worked

Answer (score 2):

Even better:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
double prefWidth = 1.0
double prefHeight = 1.0
textArea.setPrefSize(prefWidth, prefHeight);
```